# Properly linking to another web page from your home page hero section

Tags: layout, hyperlinks, homepage, marketing

I have a slight issue/disagreement with my client as far as how to add a link on the hero section that takes them to another part of the site. Before I continue, observe [this web page](http://www.spibikerally.com)

Notice I have a small paragraph on the right side that has a link to a page where people can make hotel reservations. This bike rally is taking place on a beach island and there will be tickets to purchase in order to attend.

My logical view is that only people who are willing to purchase a ticket will then think about whether or not they want to reserve a room (at a discount), so for that matter, I put tickets and hotel reservations all on the same page. My client had been insisting that I put the hotel links on the home page (which is not a very good idea to me), but became lenient about it and suggested at all costs that I put a link on the hero section that takes people to that page to reserve a hotel.

The "Buy Tickets" link already takes you to the same page anyways, so another link that says "reserve a hotel room" would be kind of redundant, but most people wouldn't know that anyways. So I added the link within the paragraph to make it more subtle. He then agreed with it but now wants it fully highlighted so that it stands out above everything.

In my opinion, I think he's putting too much focus on this link than the rally itself (mostly because he's worried that next year he won't get sponsored for the event). So my question is, what can I do here to make this link work well with the design, the layout and overall structure of the website? I've seen a lot of marketing videos criticizing the wrong wording or placement of buttons on hero pages and I just want to make this work well from a marketing perspective. Any feedback on that as well on how the website is set up is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I see it.

The Hotel Reservations are dependent on the ticket purchase.

Someone just wouldn't reserve a Room in the hotel before purchasing a ticket, because they wouldn't know if it would be available.

So, having it on the Homepage isn't really the best way to approach this problem.

The flow should be as follows: **Home page > Ticket Booking > Hotel Reservation**.

Now, since clients are adamant at most times and you've decided to include the link in the paragraph itself, which I wouldn't have had noticed if you didn't mention before.

But, it isn't in the right chronological order. Even though if it's not noticeable, it can confuse the user into reserving first and then checking the availability of the tickets.

So, you could probably have a separate section with a Background image of the Hotel's interiors, right after the Buy Ticket section where you could get creative and mention something like:

"Enjoy your stay in the beautiful South Padre Island with HOTELNAME. 10 minutes from Convention Center."

- Reserve Now!

This will bring a decent design and attraction to the hotel itself while still promoting the primary purpose: The Rally.

Comment: I was thinking of something just like that, but never really thought about it much. Ok well I'll see if I can integrate something like that soon. Today he was asking me to make the area with the page title smaller on that page so that people can see the hotels section as soon as they get there. His idea is to not make the user scroll too much..... people will have to scroll no matter what (so long as it's not a lot), so I don't think he has his priorities straight. Anyways, I'll give your idea a try.

Comment: It's been 9 days and I finally got that section on the home page going. I told him was going to do that for the home page to add emphasis on the hotel reservations. Never replied. After, I finished it, guess what? he told me to scrap the whole deal and just focus on ticket sales............ What have I've been telling him this whole time?! (sigh) I'm never doing freelancing again (thank goodness I have my regular day job). Anyways, I'm marking down your answer as correct either way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have over- looked your previous comment in the notifications.

Comment: It happens, that's a disadvantage in Freelancing, but sure does have some perks. Good to see you have a backup job. Thanks a lot! Hope this could help you in the future designs you create!